# Second interview with different department what does it mean?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment

I had a phone interview. Then after that I was called for in person interview. The position I applied was for financial support analyst which doesn't require much of programming knowledge. The hr person called me now for another interview with IT department. What does this another interview mean?
And my first interview went well with hr and manager

I am worried since I am not very good in programming. So little worried that whether the position I applied for will get affected If my interview with IT doesn't go well.

I am very much interested in the position of financial support analyst. So if my interview with IT department doesn't go well will I get the job as financial support analyst position I applied for? What do you guys think about it?

Comment: If you are confused, so are we. Ask the person who arranged the first interview what's going on. I had a recruiter who wanted to arrange an interview for me based on my extensive experience at JP Morgan and of course, I never even went there. You have to ask anyway because you need to prepare for the interview. You can't show up unprepared.

Comment: Upvoted @VietnhiPhuvan for telling you have to ask. I know it's hard for youngsters, but please understand a job interview is not an exam. It is a negotiation. They understand if you are a good fit, and you understand if they are a good fit. Feel free to ask, you guys are equal.

Comment: @Mark The relationship has to be of mutual respect based on the not unreasonable presumption that they can meet  each other's needs. Yes, the applicant needs a job. But also yes, the prospective employer needs someone to come in and do the work that's needed to help the business keep the business running.

Comment: Hi Olivia, please use the [edit] button to include new information in your post. Answers are intended for answers and not discussion. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As Mark has pointed out in the comments: the goal of the interview process is to figure out if there is a good "fit". That entails way more than just "can (s)he do the job". It's also about culture, communication styles, career growth, compensation expectations, technical growth, compatibility with the existing staff, etc.

In this context it's perfectly normal to have a second interview with a different group. A good HR department will shop an interesting candidate internally around until they are sure that they have the best "fit".

On possible conversation: "Hey, we really like the candidate. (S)he also has some decent technical chops that we really can't leverage well in finance, so chances are s(he) will get bored here after a year or so. Let's have him/her talk to IT and see if there is a better fit." Easiest way to find out, is to simply ask.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when you get referred to another department it means one of two things:

Most commonly it means that something about you impressed the orginal interviewers but they felt your skill set wasn't quite right for the job you applied for but would fit well somewhere else or they felt someone else was a better fit but they still wanted to find an organizational spot for you.

These are often new postions/vacancies they haven't yet advertised, so this tends to be a boon to the applicant.

Financial analyst to IT is a pretty big stretch though. Perhaps they saw reporting/data analysis as your strong point instead of dealing with clients and wanted to create a data analyst/big data position for you.

The other scenario that sometimes happens is that a critical vacany occurs and they think you could fill it and they have plenty of applicants for the job you applied for but need the other person urgently. Hiring you would save the time it takes to advertise and review reumes and interview many people.

All I can say is that generally when we refer the person to another position, they have a good chance of getting that position. Usually there is less competition and we have already decided they have the skill set needed and maybe the personality fit as well.

To help prepare for the interview, you should ask to see a job description of the job they have referred you to. You may find it is less hard core programming and more data analysis than you think.